# Trigger Segue Artificially

Tags: macos, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I am trying to pass data between two viewContollers in an OS X storyboard application using Swift. When I press a button on VC1, it opens VC2, and prepareForSegue is run. However, I can't pass data back to VC1 because a. prepareForSegue isn't being run (because a window isn't being opened) and b. because even if it were, VC1 doesn't know data is being sent and I can't figure out a function (something like viewDidBecomeFocus, if such a function existed) to let it know to look. I feel like there must be a way to do this.

If you know of a way to do this in IOS but not OSX, it could still be useful.
Thanks!

Comment: And here is one pretty good tutorial for delegates: [link](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/04/the-swift-swift-tutorial-why-do-we-need-delegates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that in your first ViewController you have one label and one button. When pressed, that button open popover (SecondViewController) with one textfield (and one button what says ready or close etc.), where you want take its value and assign it to your label. That is where delegates and protocols come handy.

SecondViewController:

```
@objc protocol TextDelegate {
    func passedString(textValue: String)
}

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    weak var delegate: TextDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    @IBAction func closePopOver(sender: AnyObject) {
        if delegate != nil {
            delegate!.passedString(textField.stringValue)
        }
        self.dismissViewController(self)
    }
}
```

This is ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: NSTextField!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let vc = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}

func passedString(textValue: String) {
    myLabel.stringValue = textValue
}
```